# Constraint issue: pick number within array with specific number match

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

This is the problem from my last interview as following:

Q. (Constrained randomization) Consider the lottery rules on this [page](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/lottery.html)

- Given the set of six numbers that will win the jackpot as input, try and implement the constraint to generate a set of numbers that wins the second-highest award, matching exactly 5 numbers out of the six jackpot numbers.

The Following are my code [link to EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/A5zy):

Test Bench:

```
module tb;
    initial begin
      Pick    p = new();
      p.randomize();

      $display("\nPicked result:");
      for (int i=0; i<`NUM_JACKPOT; i++)
        $write("%0d ", p.jackpot_result[i]);
      $write("\n");
      
    end
endmodule
```

Design Code:

```
`define NUM_JACKPOT  6

class Lottery;
  randc int six_jackpot_nums[`NUM_JACKPOT];
  
  constraint rand_jackpot {
    foreach (six_jackpot_nums[i])
      six_jackpot_nums[i] inside {[1:49]};
  }
endclass

class Pick;

  randc int six_jackpot_nums[`NUM_JACKPOT];
  randc int jackpot_result  [`NUM_JACKPOT];
        int award_2nd_hi = `NUM_JACKPOT -1;
 
  function pre_randomize();
    Lottery l = new();
    l.randomize();
    $display("Jackpot bingo:");
    for (int i=0; i<`NUM_JACKPOT; i++) begin
      six_jackpot_nums[i] = l.six_jackpot_nums[i];
      $write("%0d ", l.six_jackpot_nums[i]);
    end
  endfunction 
  
  constraint pick_jackpot{
    foreach (jackpot_result[i])
      jackpot_result[i] inside {[1:49]};      
    award_2nd_hi == (match(jackpot_result[0])+match(jackpot_result[1])+match(jackpot_result[2])+match(jackpot_result[3])+match(jackpot_result[4])+match(jackpot_result[5]));
  }
  
  function int match(int v);
    int tmp[$];
    tmp = six_jackpot_nums.find(x) with (x == v);
    if(tmp.size != 0) return 1;
    return 0;
  endfunction
  
  
endclass
```

For the current status, I can successfully create the Six Number Jackpot. Yet, as I creating the 2nd highest pair of numbers, I got the conflict. Please advice.

Result:

```
xmsim: *W,RNDOCS: These constraints contribute to the set of conflicting constraints:

    award_2nd_hi == (match(jackpot_result[0])+match(jackpot_result[1])+match(jackpot_result[2])+match(jackpot_result[3])+match(jackpot_result[4])+match(jackpot_result[5])); (./design.sv,31)

xmsim: *W,RNDOCS: These variables contribute to the set of conflicting constraints:


Var_Name                          Type   Status        Current_Value          Source                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
award_2nd_hi                      (S32)  STATE VAR     5 (0x5)                ./design.sv ; line 16
jackpot_result[0]                 (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  32 (0x20)              ./design.sv ; line 15
jackpot_result[1]                 (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  47 (0x2f)              ./design.sv ; line 15
jackpot_result[2]                 (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  21 (0x15)              ./design.sv ; line 15
jackpot_result[3]                 (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  40 (0x28)              ./design.sv ; line 15
jackpot_result[4]                 (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  1 (0x1)                ./design.sv ; line 15
jackpot_result[5]                 (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  27 (0x1b)              ./design.sv ; line 15
match( .v( jackpot_result[0] ) )  (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  0 (0x0)                ./design.sv ; line 31
match( .v( jackpot_result[1] ) )  (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  1 (0x1)                ./design.sv ; line 31
match( .v( jackpot_result[2] ) )  (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  0 (0x0)                ./design.sv ; line 31
match( .v( jackpot_result[3] ) )  (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  0 (0x0)                ./design.sv ; line 31
match( .v( jackpot_result[4] ) )  (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  0 (0x0)                ./design.sv ; line 31
match( .v( jackpot_result[5] ) )  (S32)  SOLVED EARLY  0 (0x0)                ./design.sv ; line 31


Jackpot bingo:
31 49 43 24 47 8
Picked result:
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach which avoids all the warnings (and errors on other simulators).  Randomly generate the set of 6 winners.  Also, randomly pick one of the winners to be replaced with a losing number.  Using `post_randomize`, create the set of losers, then randomly pick one of them and replace one of the winners.

```
`define NUM_JACKPOT  6

class Lottery;
    rand  int six_jackpot_nums[`NUM_JACKPOT];
          int jackpot_result  [`NUM_JACKPOT];
          int losers          [$];
    rand int unsigned idx;

    function void post_randomize;
        for (int i=1; i<50; i++) begin
            if (!(i inside {six_jackpot_nums})) losers.push_back(i);
        end
        losers.shuffle();
        for (int i=0; i<`NUM_JACKPOT; i++) begin
            jackpot_result[i] = (i == idx) ? losers[0] : six_jackpot_nums[i];
        end
    endfunction 

    constraint rand_jackpot {
        unique {six_jackpot_nums};
        foreach (six_jackpot_nums[i]) six_jackpot_nums[i] inside {[1:49]};
        idx inside {[1:`NUM_JACKPOT]};
    }
endclass

module tb;
    Lottery lot;
    initial begin
        lot = new();
        void'(lot.randomize());
        $display("\nPicked result:");
        for (int i=0; i<`NUM_JACKPOT; i++) $write("%0d ", lot.six_jackpot_nums[i]);
        $display("\nJackpot bingo:");
        for (int i=0; i<`NUM_JACKPOT; i++) $write("%0d ", lot.jackpot_result  [i]);
        $display;
    end
endmodule
```

Example output:

```
Picked result:
48 4 46 3 17 16 
Jackpot bingo:
48 4 21 3 17 16
```

Here, 46 is replaced by 21.

---

To address the `randc` issue noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69618986/197758), use the `unique` constraint keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration **randc** won't guarantee the array elements are unique in single randomization. So I add a constraint **unique_cons** to address this issue.

```
`define NUM_JACKPOT  6

class Lottery;
  rand int six_jackpot_nums[`NUM_JACKPOT];
  rand int jackpot_result  [`NUM_JACKPOT];
  rand int missed;
  
  constraint unique_cons {
    foreach (six_jackpot_nums[i])
      foreach(six_jackpot_nums[j])  
        if(i!=j) six_jackpot_nums[i]!=six_jackpot_nums[j];      
  }
  
  constraint valid_cons {
    foreach (six_jackpot_nums[i]){
      six_jackpot_nums[i] inside {[1:49]};
      jackpot_result[i] inside {[1:49]};
    }
  }
  constraint missed_cons {
    missed inside {[0:`NUM_JACKPOT-1]} ;    
       
  }
  constraint rand_jackpot {
    foreach (six_jackpot_nums[i])
      if(i==missed) 
        ~(jackpot_result[i] inside {six_jackpot_nums});
      else 
        jackpot_result[i] == six_jackpot_nums[i];
  } 
  
endclass
```

The results:

```
Jackpot bingo:
30 44 12 37 1 22 
Picked result:
30 44 12 37 1 9 
Jackpot bingo:
40 12 20 46 8 2 
Picked result:
40 12 20 5 8 2 
Jackpot bingo:
29 23 13 41 48 28 
Picked result:
29 39 13 41 48 28 
Jackpot bingo:
8 14 35 19 28 39 
Picked result:
8 20 35 19 28 39
```

Good call from the 1st answer, **unique** constraint keyword was enabled in systemverilog-2012.

Answer (score 2):

You should look for a solution avoiding `pre/post_randomize()` if at all possible. This makes it much easier to override or add more constraints when all constraints and random variables are solved at once.

```
parameter int JACKPOT_NUM = 6;

class Lottery;
  rand int six_jackpot_nums[JACKPOT_NUM];
  rand int pick_result_nums[JACKPOT_NUM];
  
  constraint jack_rand {
    unique {six_jackpot_nums};
    foreach(six_jackpot_nums[i]) six_jackpot_nums[i] inside {[1:49]};
    unique {pick_result_nums};
    foreach(pick_result_nums[i]) pick_result_nums[i] inside {[1:49]};
  }
  constraint pick5 {
    pick_result_nums.sum() with (int'(item == six_jackpot_nums[item.index])) == 5;
  }
 
endclass

module tb;
    initial begin
      static Lottery l = new();
      repeat(3) begin
        assert(l.randomize());
        $display("\nBingo result:");
        foreach(l.six_jackpot_nums[i])
          $write("%0d ", l.six_jackpot_nums[i]);
        $display("\nPicked result:");
        foreach(l.six_jackpot_nums[i])
          $write("%0d ", l.pick_result_nums[i]);
        $write("\n");
      end
      
    end
endmodule
```

Doing it this way lets you add more constraints, like *"the picked number that does not match must be one greater than the jackpot number"*. That of course leaves 49 from being chosen as the missed jackpot number, but it also leaves out missing any the first of any two sequential jackpot numbers.